# Binding is not working for indeterminate state for CheckBox in UinversalWindows

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a CheckBox and I have bind the nullable bool property for IsChecked property like below, but the indeterminate is not working, it shows uncheck state.

```
     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectAll1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource viewmodel}}"/>
 private bool? isselectAll1 = true;
    public bool? IsSelectAll1
    {
        get
        {
            return isselectAll1;
        }
        set
        {
            isselectAll1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelectAll1");
        }
    }
```

But if i directly set the value for IsChecked as {x:Null} it works fine. Only Binding does not work.

Can any one provide the suggestion for this?

Comment: Set IsThreeState=true for checkbox

Comment: IsThreeState = true is not works

Comment: Does not appear to work as it does with desktop WPF -- sounds like it might not be supported in store apps http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-in-winrt-xaml-you-cannot.html